# Jackson don't automatically convert complexy names of fields from json-object into dto-object

Tags: spring-boot, rest, jackson

Jackson don't automatically convert complexy names of fields from json-object into dto-object.

I have gotten a request

```java
 @PostMapping(path = "model/byFile")
public ResponseEntity<ModelDto>
    createModel(@RequestBody List<DataFileDto> modelList) {
}
```

- dto

```java
public class DataFileDto {

   @NotNull
   String kyId;

    @NotNull
    String nameAs;

//default constructor

//getters and setter

//Builder

}
```

When json arrives, when converting, Jackson takes out the value and puts it only in simple words , but writes null in compound words.

To avoid this, I have to use the **@JsonProperty("ky_id")** property, which I find inconvenient. The project itself is old. I can't add there

```xml
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

or

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

because then the project will break.

I also noticed that there was a custom ObjectMapper configuration set up there.

```java
@Bean
  public ObjectMapper mapper() {
    var module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(BigDecimal.class, new BigDecimalSerializer());

    var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS, true);
    return objectMapper;
  }
```

**update**

I added

```java
...
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
...
```

thanks

What could have affected the fact that Jackson does not work properly with compound words, despite the fact that setters and getters are present ?

How can this be fixed ?

Comment: You said yourself how to fix it, with the JsonProperty annotation. I think you could also configure your objectMapper with your naming strategy using .setPropertyNamingStrategy() method

Comment: (...JsonProperty annotation.) -I have objects with a large number of fields, so it's not an option to place this above the fields

Comment: then use the global configuration in your mapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think we can talk about "affecting". I think it's about the default configuration of Jackson. If you want a different behaviour you have either to use the `@JsonProperty` annotation or have a global configuration with `objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(my strategy here)`.

Comment: ....out of the box, it always worked with compound words without any problems, I just now encountered such a situation (although I may not remember, I may have already met this, but I did not attach any importance)

Comment: @skyho I'm not sure what you mean with "compound words". What I'm saying is that if the case is not matching the strategy, it won't work. Considering you have `objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)` if the name is not matching the strategy I think it will just be treated as an unknown property and it will be ignored.

Comment: "compound words" , for example - 'key_id' or 'server_port_id'

Comment: @skyho is the global configuration of the naming strategy solving your issue then?

Comment: @skyho would you accept my answer if it solved your issue? :) Thanks!